# Add a custom attribute to an element in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a custom attribute on my element using jquery :

```
$('.map-areas-div').rand(numElements).each(function(){
      $(this).attr('element_id',4);
});
```

But in the end, my elements doesn't have a "element_id" attribute.

PS, my html elements look like :

```
<div type="ground" class="map-areas-div" style="position: absolute; top: 900px; left: 720px; height: 40px; width: 90px;"></div>
```

Thank you for help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. Use jQuery.data api instead to associate custom properties with element's jQuery wrapper. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: That's a solution but the attribute doesn't appear in the html :( It's hardest for tests :)

Comment: You cannot add custom attributes to html elements using JS. But data() should solve your problem. You however can insert strings into element  using setting innerHTML, but JS won't give it.

Answer (score 23):

you can use jQuery .data() functionality.

```
var theDiv = $('#' + divID).data('winWidth', value);
```

Get the data back using

```
theDiv.data('winWidth');
```

Comment: Best answer for its simplicity and versatility

Answer (score 9):

I use the jQuery on-the-fly technique to accomplish that hack.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('<div>').attr('id', 'attributename').attr('faron', 'Idunnoyoucanseeme').text('Hello, I am the element with made-up attribute built on the fly.  Made up attribute: faron').appendTo('#nest');

  var attributegrabber = $('#attributename').attr('faron');

  alert(attributegrabber);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nest"></div>
```

Comment: This works for fundamental types, but not for complex types (functions, object literals, etc.). The data attribute methods work for both.

Comment: @Hollister :: as per your comment - not to challenge you but aknowledging your point but also to point my point alongside.  As per current jQuery version, you can have customized data attribute of your choice.  i.e.  with lightbox.js, its data attribute stood as `data-lightbox`.

Answer (score 8):

**You can add/set custom attribute in image also**

```
var attr = 'data-img';
var message = 'Hello'
jQuery('img').attr(attr,message);
```

it will result

```
<img src="xyz.jpg" data-img="Hello">
```

Comment: Worked fine, without using `jQuery.data`

Comment: @Przemyslaw.Pszemek Great to hear from you.

Answer (score -3):

First check

```
$(this).css('background', 'url(' + randomItem.src + ')');
```

is working or not? If its working, put '' to your add attribute code like,

```
$(this).attr('element_id','4');
```